# Check for path existence in Artifactory through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops, artifactory

I have a Jenkins job that uploads multiple files to Artifactory and I'd like it to check for each file's path before actual upload with the following observations:

- If the path does not exist for one file, I don't want that file to be uploaded. With the mention that rest of the files to be checked and not to fail the job.
- If there is already a the path created I want my job to continue and create upload the files.

Do you have any idea how should I implement this?
Any idea/approach will help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow you mentioned is already implemented in the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. The plugin has an internal checksum-based upload optimization. This feature is supported out of the box and already enabled in all generic upload job types:

[Scripted Pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles), [Declarative Pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles) and [Freestyle job Generic upload](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Generic+Builds).

Before uploading a file using one of the above methods, the Jenkins Artifactory plugin:

1. Calculates the checksum of the file.
2. Sends a PUT request to Artifactory with the checksum, but without the content of the file.

If the empty PUT request returned 200 - the new path is added to the artifact in Artifactory, so we don't have to upload it again.

If the empty PUT request returned 404 - we do a regular file upload.

This feature does not related to the target path of the file in Artifactory. Even if you see the file in other path, it is enough to skip uploading it again.